# SimpleGraphClient: Invalid token received

Tags: oauth, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I started developing a new MS Teams Application and I am trying to authenticate a MS Teams user on my app's backend by following the source code of
https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/app-sso

But unfortunately when I am trying to create a SimpleGraphClient with the token acquired by this function

```
// Get Access Token
const getAccessToken = async(req) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const { tenantId, token } = reqData(req);

        const scopes = ['User.Read']; //['User.Read', 'email', 'offline_access', 'openid', 'profile'];
        const url = `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${ tenantId }/oauth2/v2.0/token`;
        const params = {
            client_id: process.env.MicrosoftAppId,
            client_secret: process.env.MicrosoftAppPassword,
            grant_type: 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer',
            assertion: token,
            requested_token_use: 'on_behalf_of',
            scope: scopes.join(' ')
        };

        // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
        fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: querystring.stringify(params),
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
        }).then(result => {
            if (result.status !== 200) {
                result.json().then(json => {
                    // eslint-disable-next-line prefer-promise-reject-errors
                    reject({ error: json.error });
                });
            } else {
                result.json().then(async json => {
                    resolve(json.access_token);
                });
            }
        });
    });
};
```

I am taking the exception :
throw new Error('SimpleGraphClient: Invalid token received.');
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please send an example of how you are calling this function in the first place, from the front end. Are you setting the Authorization header correctly, to a Bearer token value? When you debug the code above, on the server side, you should have a valid JWT token in the 'token' variable.

Comment: This is an older sample, and it calls Graph directly - the latest guidance is to rather call your own API and proxy all Graph calls through there, so bear that in mind, but the sample may help to show the front end/back end part better than the one you are referring to now.

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow that's what I am doing right now this is a backend function I have checked the token with jwt.io and it seems ok

Comment: You can see directly in the sample where that exception is being raised. It's [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/blob/main/samples/app-sso/nodejs/server/models/simpleGraphClient.js#L14) and it's appearing because the token being passed to the `SimpleGraphClient` is empty. Clearly something is going wrong in your code - have you debugged to look for the what's actually coming back from your `fetch` call?

Comment: Also, out of interest, why have you written your own auth code, instead of using the MSAL library, like in the sample? It already had a very reasonable-looking getAuthToken method at https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/blob/main/samples/app-sso/nodejs/server/services/authService.js

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow thank you for your answer! May I ask something? I am not sure if I am using the right MicrosoftAppPassword can you clarify where I can get it? Regards

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow right now I am using the secret from 'Certificates & secrets'

Comment: Yes, that's the correct one, spot on. Here's a really good intro video on the topic: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SaBbfVgqZHc

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft I will see the proposed video and I will get back to you